# Nextjs Firebase auth state not persisting

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication

I have no idea why firebase auth is not persisting. My project is super simple so far, i have this sign in function.

```
await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
```

And in the `layout.tsx` I have the `onAuthStateChange`

```
const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("the current user is: ", user);
      if (!user) {
        router.replace("/sign-in");
        return;
      } else {
        router.replace("/main");
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

And that's it. I can sign in and i get redirected, but when i reload the page there's no user anymore.

Next version is 14.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The onAuthStateChanged triggers only when you sign/signout with firebase.
So you might need to add your subscription inside context provider & store the user object in state & pass them as a prop to context provider.

```
     const authenticate = getAuth(initializeApp(firebaseConfig));

        const AuthContext = createContext<any>({});
        export const useAuth = () => useContext<any>(AuthContext); 
        export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
          const [user, setUser] = useState<any>({ email: null, uid: null ,displayName : null});
          const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState<boolean>(true);
        
        
          useEffect(() => {
            const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(authenticate, (user) => {
              if (user) {
                setUser({
                  email: user.email,
                  uid: user.uid,
                  displayName: user.displayName,
                  initializing:initializing,
                });
              } else {
                  
                setUser({ email: null, uid: null, displayName:null, initializing:true});
              }
              setInitializing(false);
            });
            return () => unsubscribe();
          }, [initializing]);
        
        
          return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{initializing ? null : children}</AuthContext.Provider>
          );
        };
```

then using the context, you can check from your page/layout/middleware to redirect

```
 const { user } = useAuth();   
 if(!user)
   router.replace("/sign-in");
    else
   router.replace("/main");
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, I am signing in with google. But after i reload the page, the auth state should persist. It's not persisting, there's no signed in user after that.

Comment: Do you see any firebase session stored in browser after you login before reloading

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` inside of a server action?

It seems that when you are calling that function inside a server action or a server component it doesn't save the response on the local storage of the browser making the `onAuthStateChanged` malfunction as it's not getting any data from the local storage of the browser